# xlwings, Python to Excel output of multiple cells with different values

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, xlwings

I am trying to have this program have its output go into multiple cells with different values.

I want to have the output of the if-statement have its output go into multiple excel cells, but with different values as the value of `x` changes in the `partnum_list`. What's currently happening is the script puts the same number into the cells I listed. Which makes sense, but I would like for the adjacent cells change value with each change of `x`

```
#this is where the f***in' magic happens!
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('ROT Replenishment Schedule - no replenishments.xlsx')
wb_output = xw.Book('PytoExcelTestShit.xlsx')
out_sheet = wb_output.sheets[0]
rep_sheet = wb.sheets[1]

 
#number panel
p_num_in = input("What panel are you at? ")
p_num = float(p_num_in)
    

#a bunch of fn numbers
reel_tot_list = rep_sheet.range('A2:A155').value
partnum_list = rep_sheet.range('E2:E155').value
ppb_list = rep_sheet.range('G2:G155').value
 
#LIST STARTS AT x = 0, subtract 3 from excel cell number
x = 0

# time (min) until replenishment
t_rep = 15

#shown as tao - the panel at which replemishment will occur
panel_rep = t_rep / 3

while(x <= 151):
    
    x += 1 
    
    #total parts on reel
    r_tot = reel_tot_list[x]
    
    #Parts Per Build
    ppb = ppb_list[x]
 

    #reel quantity at replenishment
    r_rep = abs( ( ( ( r_tot / ppb ) - panel_rep) * ppb) - r_tot)
    
    #distance to replenishment (parts remaining)
    curr_dist = ( (r_tot -  (ppb * p_num) ) - r_rep )
       
    #Output fxn
    def replenishment (r_tot, ppb, r_rep, curr_dist, panel_rep):
     
        print("")
        
        print("*********************************************")
        
        print('P#: '+partnum_list[x])
        
        
    
        
        print("Replenishment will occur at (panels): " + str(round((r_tot/ppb)-(r_rep/ppb))))
        print("Replenishment will occur at (parts remaining): " + str(r_rep))
        
        print("")
        
        print("Current distance to replemishment (panels): " + str(round(curr_dist/ppb)))
        print("Current distance to replemishment (parts remaining): " + str(curr_dist))
        
        print("")
        
        print("Current time until replemishment (min): "+ str(round(( curr_dist / ppb ) * panel_rep )))
            
        print("*********************************************")
        
    
    #deciding when to output
    if( round(( curr_dist / ppb ) * panel_rep)  <= 6 and round(( curr_dist / ppb ) * panel_rep)  >= 0): 
        out_sheet.range('D3:D155').value = partnum_list[x]
        out_sheet.range('E4:E155').value = 'REPLENISH NOW'
        replenishment(r_tot, ppb, r_rep, curr_dist, panel_rep)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear reproduce with no understanding of the data content. The main question is vague. Are you saying; at this line `out_sheet.range('D3:O4').value = partnum_list[x]`:- for each element in the list `partnum_list` is to be entered into a separate cell in the range D3:O4? Although `partnum_list` looks like it has 155 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my question. For any of the outputs to an excel file I changed the range from `out_sheet.range('E3:E155').value = '*REPLENISH NOW*'` to  `out_sheet.range('E'+str(x)).value = '*REPLENISH NOW*'`

this is so that the output can takw advantage of the value of `x` to know where to place the output, and what to place in the out cells